# Bitbucket pipeline failing while running Newman collection with images as multi-part form data

Tags: multipartform-data, bitbucket-pipelines, postman-collection-runner, newman

I want run newman collection which requires images too as multipart form data.

How can I run newman test collection on Bitbucket pipeline so that it can take images too? I couldn't find anything like this.

Script that I used:

```
image: postman/newman_alpine33

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
    script:
    - newman --version
    - newman run ./ocrCollection/Pipelinedemo.postman_collection.json
```

I have added the image in the collection folder in the repo as well.
I am getting this error:

[image: Bitbucket folder]

[image: Pipeline failing]
[image: Pipeline error]

How can I run tests using the images?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the `--working-dir <path>` flag in your Newman command? Without that, it would default to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks Danny, I referred your github link to start off. 
Yeah I changed the path in JSON collection file. Actually collection was unable to take pictures from the path specified because path in the collection was the path on my local machine. So I changed it in the JSON collection file in the repo and it worked.